# Stop all animations on hovering 1 object with the same classes

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

well, my problem is in the title. I need help to stop all @keyframes by hovering one of main-section__*. Im already exhausted, I have to go to study in a couple of hours, and I spent the whole night behind this code. help me please :(((.

( how to post it, how many details I have to describe in order to post on the site ).

In this case main-section__title hold itself a title of the site, next 8 div's are look like circles with their thematic icon.

On any of my methods, the maximum result that I can achieve is to stop the animation on only one of the 8 circles.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="main-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-section__title">Resume</div>
            <div class="main-section__about-me anim-stop"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="main-section__skills anim-stop"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="main-section__contacts anim-stop"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="main-section__languages anim-stop"><i class="fa fa-language fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="main-section__working-exp anim-stop"><i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="main-section__courses anim-stop"><i class="fa fa-certificate fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="main-section__post anim-stop"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="main-section__education anim-stop"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**SCSS**:

```
.main-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba($color: #bde0fe, $alpha: 0.2);
  &__title {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #a2d2ff;
  }
  &__about-me {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 43.5%;
    left: 46.75%;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-250px);
    animation: 30s linear 0s infinite normal $animation-play main-section-about-me;
    @keyframes main-section-about-me {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
    }
    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20.5%;
      left: 21%;
    }
    &:hover {
      @for $elem from 1 through 10 {
        .anim-stop:nth-child(#{$elem}) {
          animation-play-state: paused;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  &__skills {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 43.5%;
    left: 46.75%;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-250px);
    animation: 30s linear 0s infinite normal $animation-play main-section-skills;
    @keyframes main-section-skills {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(405deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
    }
    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      left: 16%;
    }
  }
  &__contacts {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 43.5%;
    left: 46.75%;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-380px);
    animation: 30s linear 0s infinite normal $animation-play main-section-contacts;
    @keyframes main-section-contacts {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(450deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
    }
    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 22.5%;
      left: 27.5%;
    }
  }
  &__languages {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 43.5%;
    left: 46.75%;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-380px);
    animation: 30s linear 0s infinite normal $animation-play main-section-languages;
    @keyframes main-section-languages {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(135deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(495deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
    }
    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 23%;
      left: 25%;
    }
  }
  &__working-exp {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 43.5%;
    left: 46.75%;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-380px);
    animation: 30s linear 0s infinite normal $animation-play main-section-working-exp;
    @keyframes main-section-working-exp {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(540deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
    }
    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 22.5%;
      left: 21.25%;
    }
  }
  &__courses {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 43.5%;
    left: 46.75%;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-380px);
    animation: 30s linear 0s infinite normal $animation-play main-section-courses;
    @keyframes main-section-courses {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(225deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(585deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
    }
    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 21%;
      left: 25%;
    }
  }
  &__post {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 43.5%;
    left: 46.75%;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-380px);
    animation: 30s linear 0s infinite normal $animation-play main-section-post;
    @keyframes main-section-post {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(630deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
    }
    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 21%;
      left: 33.5%;
    }
  }
  &__education {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 43.5%;
    left: 46.75%;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-380px);
    animation: 30s linear 0s infinite normal $animation-play main-section-education;
    @keyframes main-section-education {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(315deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(675deg) translateY(-250px);
      }
    }
    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 25%;
      left: 13%;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer was right before my eyes - it is JS. But if someone can tell me how to make this feature only on css, please take my thanks. i would like to know if it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set

```
.anim-stop{
animation-play-state: paused;}
```

Then toggle the class using the onmouseover event:

```
<div onmouseover="myToggleFunction()" class="main-section">
```

Comment: well youre my savior, i tried to do this only on css but didnt even think about js